# Declaring a new Array with a larger size within a method that does not return

Tags: java, arrays, oop, methods

I am currently filling in a section of code and in it one of the methods I have to make a new array double the size and fill it in with the old values, which I did, but how do I make it so that the new array is the one that is used from now on if the method doesn't return anything?

```
private void upSize()
{
    String[] biggerArr = new String[theArray.length*2];
    for( int i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++)
        biggerArr[i] = theArray[i];
}
```

So obviously this code is built to not return anything, but when it gets called somewhere like here, how do I actually increase the size of that array so that it can fit the new "Added" element.

```
 public boolean add( T element ){
    if (size() == theArray.length) upSize();
    theArray[count++] = element;
    return true;
}
```

I'm sorry if this was something that already has an answered thread, I did a lot of searching through and couldn't find anything that touched on this specifically.

Comment: `biggerArr` is a local variable. What do you expect it to change?

Comment: BTW: `Arrays.copyOf(theArray, theArray.length * 2)` will return an array twice the length.

Comment: Simply add `theArray = biggerArr;` to the end of `upSize()`, so the `theArray` *field* gets updated with the new larger array.

Comment: I'm new here so I don't exactly know if i can/how to respond to people, but Andy Turner that was my problem. Normally i would just return it, but I can't return it, but thank you for the Arrays.copyOf tip. Also Andreas I believe that is exactly what I was looking for thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You have to return new array and assign it to the existing reference, like this:

```
private String[] upSize()
{
    String[] biggerArr = new String[theArray.length*2];
    for( int i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++)
        biggerArr[i] = theArray[i];
    return biggerArr;
}

 public boolean add( T element ){
    if (size() == theArray.length) theArray = upSize();
    theArray[count++] = element;
    return true;
}
```

But look at `java.util.ArrayList`, you won't have to reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: There is no need to return the array, it would be sufficient to just make that assignment after the new array was filled. And note that your second method returns true all the time, that is absolutely pointless.

Comment: Right, it would be just enough to reassign `theArray = biggerArr;` at the end of `upSize` method. Second method already had `return true` statement so it was not my idea to put it there.

Comment: Nothing prevents front telling the questioner what other things in his code could be improved.